# Buttons BackPack Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I need some help on the backpack, the buttons.
I have a list of `products`, and in the `edit` and `delete` buttons I have added two more to the `nutrient` of a product and its `price`. Using the backpack I do not know how to load the id of the product in question to put this additional information. How can I do it?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf60b.png)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the button view you created you should be able to use `$entry`. Check out https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-buttons for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this event happened more than 1 month, I'll try to share some information to help others.

**1. First of all you need to create a new blade file**

resources\views\vendor\backpack\buttons\crud\buttons.

**2. Inside of your file**

```
<a href="nutrientes?produto_id={{$entry->getKey()}}"><i class='fa fa-list'></i>Listar Nutrientes</a>
```

The $entry->getKey() is going to provide the "id" to you.

**3. Connecting the "Button" to your CrudCrontroller**

Inside your ProductCrudController you need to add a new entry.

```
$this->crud->addButtonFromView('line', 'extra_button', 'extra_button', 'beginning');
```

the extra_button "just a example" needs to have the name of your blade file in the third parameter "if i'm not wrong".

After this you should get your new button for each line listed in the table.

> Just a tip: If you're going to add "a lot of buttons" try to use a
>   drop down button.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-xs btn-default">
        <span class="fa fa-list" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #f1f1f1"></span> &nbsp;
        <span data-value="save_and_back" style="color: #fff">Opções</span>
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-xs btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aira-expanded="false" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">▼</span>
    </button><div class="dropdown-backdrop"></div>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="font-size: 12px;">
        <li><a href="test/create/{{$entry->getKey()}}" data-value="save_and_edit"><i class='fa fa-plus'></i>Add new nutriente</a></li>
        <li><a href="nutrientes?produdo_id={{$entry->getKey()}}" data-value="save_and_edit"><i class='fa fa-list'></i>Listar nutrientes</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/secondaction{{$entry->getKey()}}" data-value="save_and_edit"><i class='fa fa-arrow-right'></i>Second Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="teste/cancel/{{$entry->getKey()}}" data-value="save_and_edit"><i class='fa fa-times'></i>Cancel</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```